# How to encrypt/decrypt with only encryption hardware?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Alice and Bob have agreed a symmetric key to be used for encrypting messages to be sent over an insecure (wrt a passive adversary) communication channel. Both of them have hardware devices for carrying out the encryption, but no (hardware or software) decrypting tools.

Nevertheless, they have to setup a simple scheme for securing the privacy, based on hardware encryptors, allowing the sender to encrypt a message and the recipient to decrypt a message.

How to Design the scheme?

Comment: How can you only be able to encrypt? Who would even design such hard- or software?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem, and we are missing the context.

Comment: I think that answer is like using a "forward" encryption in both sides. So maybe answer is just using a stream cipher with CFB or OFB mode of operation. The parties will use then the same hardware resources.

Comment: If there are no decrypting tools, how are the messages to be decrypted?

Comment: because they will do the same operation just with slightly different input exploiting XOR properties!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I thought something about the XOR operation. If I'm not wrong XOR is symmetrical so if you apply `a XOR k XOR k` you obtain `a` again. So for encryption you can use just a XOR, and for the decryption you can use another XOR.

Comment: Yes this is correct. They will use the same available hardware both for encryption and decryption so this is the answer.